# Extract the provided text + whole paragraph where ever the text present in webpage python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to extract given text which is present, can be anywhere in the Webpage without using CssSelector, Xpath, ClassName, etc...

I have the following code:

```
 keyword = raw_input("Please Enter The Keyword to Search : ")
 from selenium import webdriver   
 driver = webdriver.Chrome()#path is already setuped
 driver.get(url)
 driver.implicitly_wait(5)
 # Not providing Expected output
 # dataa = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), "+keyword+")]") 
 dataa = driver.page_source
 driver.quit()
```

Earlier I used this code to do the same text extraction process but with bs4 and that worked successfully.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
for da in soup.find_elements(text=re.compile(keyword)):
    print da.text
```

Is there any method so that I can only extract paragraphs or description using the keyword?

Answer (score 0):

So what if you extract all text on page using 'goose' module, then iterate over everything and find keyword in given sentence, something like this:

```
from goose import Goose

keyword = 'I can only extract paragraphs'

g = Goose(config={'enable_image_fetching':False})
article = g.extract(url='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44444456/extract-the-provided-text-whole-paragraph-where-ever-the-text-present-in-webpa')
text = article.cleaned_text
_sent = [sent for sent in text.split('\n') if keyword in sent]

print _sent
#[u'is there any method ?? so that ""I can only extract paragraphs or Description using the keyword""']
```

UPDATE: extra module required: pyteaser. Function returns first 5 sents based on scoring for provided keyword

```
from pyteaser import Summarize
from goose import Goose

def teaser(title,text):
    summaries = Summarize(title,text)
    return summaries



g = Goose(config={'enable_image_fetching':False})
article = g.extract(url='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rahul_Dravid')
text = article.cleaned_text

print teaser('Dravid',text)
```

Comment: if you need whole paragraph just check keyword inclusion in text `if keyword in article.cleaned_text:`

Comment: sorry to say that this really didn't provide me the solution what I want. #brc

Comment: could you be more specific? taking as example current webpage, what data needs to be extracted and what keyword to be used?

Comment: can you help me to extract all the "keyword" word and related information to it present in this page

Comment: for example i need to extract a keyword = "Dravid" from url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rahul_Dravid". I want all the occurrence of Dravid from the webpage. The links and keywords are not constant it depend upon the user.

Comment: what do you imply for "related information" ? is it a sentence where "keyword" is found, entire text or paragraph ?

Comment: The "related information" is the number of complete paragraphs/lines depending upon the occurrence of keywords in it.

Comment: sorry, the solution provided doesn't match.